# Await for user input/message with python-telegram-bot and asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a library of components to work with telegram bot that I could execute in order. Each component would await it's input and allow execution to continue to the next line, like so:

```
fname = await Question().run('Enter first name')
lname = await Question().run('Enter last name')
```

While allowing other coroutines to run elsewhere in the code.
I implemented Question like so:

```
class Question:
   def __init__(self):
      self.result = None
   
   async def on_message(self, update, context):
     self.result = update.message.text

   async def run(self, prompt):
     # register on_message as handler
     # prompt user
     while self.result is None:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
     # unregister on_message handler
     return self.result
```

This loop would block the on_message functionality and user input is never received

I tried using series of awaited recursive calls instead of the loop. Same result.

I tried using threading and putting the loop into separate Thread. Same result.

I ended up doing this with a chain of callbacks, but this I could have done without any asynchronous stuff, and it is plain ugly.

Please tell me there is a way to achieve what I want.

Comment: In your design `run` does not return until an answer is available.  Therefore this Task is paused awaiting a result.  So the call to on_message has to happen somewhere else, either in another Task or another thread.  As you say, you are allowing other coroutines to run.  One of those other coroutines has to be the one making the call to `on_message`.  Can you show us how you launch that other Thread or Task?  (BTW it is much better to use one of the synchronization primitives, for example asyncio.Event, than a polling loop.)

Comment: You may be interested in this thread: https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/pull/3042